# How to get JavaFX HBoxes to move items to the next line?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I'm trying to show a HBox which contains a list of checkboxes. Example:

```
HBox container = new HBox();
for (Weekday day: Weekday.values() )
{
   container.getChildren().add( new CheckBox( day.getName() ) ); 
}
```

However this shows the days all on one line, as:

```
Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
```

The window is not big enough to show them all on one line, and so I get a horizontal scrollbar. What I need is to show the days on two lines, e.g:

```
Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday
Thursday Friday Saturday
```

I've tried `container.setPrefWidth()` but it just causes it to show `Su.., Mo..` to truncate the text rather than moving them to the next line.

Comment: dynamically use multiple HBoxes inside a VBox?

Comment: @doomsdaymachine that seems a bit hackish, and if I ever needed to add/remove controls, it'd be a pain. Is there no way to make HBox work this way automatically?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should try using FlowPane. I tried it and got the result you've been seeking for.

> The HBox layout pane provides an easy way for arranging a series of nodes in a single row
>
> ...
>
> The nodes within a FlowPane layout pane are laid out consecutively and wrap at the boundary set for the pane. Nodes can flow vertically (in columns) or horizontally (in rows). A vertical flow pane wraps at the height boundary for the pane. A horizontal flow pane wraps at the width boundary for the pane.

source: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG
(its a useful read)

Comment: +1 for FlowPane. Or TilePane if you want the nodes to be all the same size.

Comment: I feel I should kiss you, I have stupidly been trying to achieve this same functionality for a couple of hours now.